# How do I detect DbConnection type name from Connection string only

Tags: .net, parsing, connection-string, dbconnection, dbproviderfactories

Is there new or existing method to parse a connection string’s keys to determine the connection type (OleDbConnection, OdbcConnection, SqlConnection, MySqlConnection, DB2Connetrion, etc) ?

It needs to be using either .NET Standard or .NET Core or .NET 5, not .Net Framework.

The result returned should be either a string of the name or an enum of connection types parsed names, not an actual DbConnection.

Was thinking of using DbConnectionStringBuilder and if it contains key:

- “provider” return “OleDbConnection”.
- “driver” return “OdbcConnection”.

It’s all the other connection string providers I need help identifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *why* you need to identify which provider a connection string corresponds to. If it's to automatically guess which provider to use you should probably consider supplying  both a connection string and a provider explicitly. Guessing the provider based solely on the connection string is just that: a guess. It can not be a foolproof solution.

That being said, here are some pointers to common ADO.NET providers with the list of keywords used in their connection strings.

- [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) keywords: [SqlConnectionString.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/v2.1.1/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/Common/DbConnectionStringCommon.cs#L734-L786) ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder))
- [Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/) keywords: [NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/v5.0.1.1/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs#L277-L1422) ([documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html))
- [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) keywords: [MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/8.0.22/MySQL.Data/src/MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs#L44-L215) ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-6-10-connection-options.html))
- [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) keywords: [MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/1.2.1/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs#L505-L760) ([documentation](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/))
- [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/) keywords: [SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v5.0.1/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.cs#L22-L29) ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings))
- [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/) keywords: [SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder.cs](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/file?name=System.Data.SQLite/SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder.cs)
- [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) and [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/) keywords: [OracleConnectionStringBuilder documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#CJAEDBGH)

From there, you can extract all the keywords and write a heuristic that computes what is the most likely provider for a given connection string.

Comment: You are right it would just be a guess, but I was just hoping there might be some possible way.